# Is there a correlation between the susceptibility of a polymer to undergo hydrolysis and its melting point?

Tags: polymers, melting-point, hydrolysis

As per topic, I was wondering why the Tm of the polymers PGA, PLA and PLGA are in the following order. Does it correlate to their ability to undergo hydrolysis?

PGA>PLA>PLGA

Comment: I don't have the information available to do more than comment, but rates of hydrolysis (generally) are PGA > PLGA > PLA. The hydrolysis rates are controlled by the **sequence**, e.g. GG hydrolyzes faster than GL or lG, which hydrolyze faster than LL (all for steric reasons). Melting point has to do with the overall order of the polymer. Tm of PLGA depends on composition, sequence, polymerization method, and control of stereochemistry.

Comment: Off the cuff answer: in solution Tm would have no effect.  Out of solution (ie caustic solution applied to solid polymer), surface wetability for the solvent carrying base would be a much stronger component than Tm.  Well underneath the Tms, no change would be observed.  However, lower Tm at a temperature near the Tm would result in better adsorption by solution all other things being equal, so the 'ability' to undergo hydrolysis (generally described as a rate) would be higher.  All of that being said, I think Tg would be more important than Tm, but less important than wetability.